# How can crop rectangle area?

Tags: android, canvas, android-camera, crop, android-camera-intent

Hi i am working on **android** application to detect page number using camera preview. After I received frame I draw a rectangle on **surface view** Using **Canvas** and I want to **crop** the rectangle area to put it in a bitmap, so please how can I do it ?[image: as shown here]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have the bitmap of the frame, you can use

```
Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBmp, rectanglePositionX, rectanglePositionY, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight);
```

Assuming you know where your rectangle is positioned and its dimensions.

Comment: i draw the rectangle by touch screen using **onTouch** so is it rectanglePositionX and rectanglePositionY same event.getX() and event.getY()?

Comment: So in that case you should probably store the event.getX() and event.getY() some where and use those to crop the image ?

Comment: cropping with wrong x and width, y and height seems fine.

Comment: Hello @Vishnuvardhan, did you solved that wrong x-positions while cropping? i to have same issue. If yes, can you please explain your solution?